# SlickGrid grid acts like position:fixed relative to browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, grid, slickgrid

This is driving me crazy. The grid is not staying in position inside the element div but rather it acts like it is on a fixed position in the browser window. So if I scroll down the grid follows down rather than staying put. Is this something that needs to be specified in options or is there something wrong in my script?

I'm using the example from github.

```
var grid;
var columns = [
{id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title"},
{id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration"},
{id: "%", name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete"},
{id: "start", name: "Start", field: "start"},
{id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish"},
{id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven"}
```

];

```
var options = {
enableCellNavigation: true,
enableColumnReorder: false
```

};

```
$(function () {
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  data[i] = {
    title: "Task " + i,
    duration: "5 days",
    percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
    start: "01/01/2009",
    finish: "01/05/2009",
    effortDriven: (i % 5 == 0)
  };
}

grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```

})

Comment: Please post your html code(`myGrid`) also

Comment: The grid behaves properly...u might have mentioned position: fixed somewhere... please put html and css of mygrid